# Jpeg quantization table (16x16)

Tags: compression, dct, quantization

I try to study jpeg image compression. I've got one problem for quantization step, I am not able to find quantization table for matrices 16x16.  I am searching for the matlab code for JPEG quantization table (16x16) for digital image compression using dct.Any links or resources that I can lookup?

Answer (score -1):

JPEG always uses 8x8 matrices.